# PHP and MySQL - Select statment not returning correct order

Tags: php, mysql, select, join, distinct

I have the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT user.user_id 
FROM (post INNER JOIN user ON user.user_id = post.user_id) 
WHERE post.red_flag = 0 AND post.approved = 1 
AND user.official = 1 
AND post.activity_date >= '2012-01-13' 
ORDER BY post.activity_date DESC LIMIT 6
```

I am trying to get the newest post from users who are officials, approved, within the last 30 days.

It seems the problem is that the query is finding the first distinct value of a user_id and using the date attached to that row. It goes through the table in no particular order, finds user_id 15 and flags that as unique. Then every other record with the user_id of 15 is passed over. The record I want with the newest date is one that is passed over.

How do I get it to return the newest distinct posts?

Answer (score 1):

You are not selecting posts, you are selecting user_id's from the table `user`.

Without knowing your table-structure, I would guess you need something like:

```
SELECT post.id FROM post LEFT JOIN user
  ON user.user_id = post.user_id
WHERE post.red_flag = 0
  AND post.approved = 1
  AND user.official = 1
  AND post.activity_date >= '2012-01-13'
GROUP BY post.user_id
ORDER BY post.activity_date DESC
LIMIT 6
```

I added a `GROUP BY` clause as it seems you want to return only one post per user.